# Why does CRM 2011 create two fields in the database for Money datatypes?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

Why does CRM 2011 create two fields in the database for Money datatypes?

For example a property on an entity called "Reserve Price" will have two fields created in the database;

```
ReservePrice (money, null)
reserveprice_Base (money, null)
```

Both have the same data. Why does CRM do this.

Comment: More to the point, why are you looking at the database directly? The CRM database was not meant to be read by humans. Any changes you make will be unsupported by Microsoft.

Comment: Apart from the completely supported FilteredViews, where this concept also applies

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The base field contains the amount of money using the system default currency (let's say this is USD). The other field contains the amount of money using the Currency lookup on that record (let's say this is set to EUROS).

So, if you put in a value of 1 in that field, and set the currency to EUROS, then when the record is saved, the system will put "1" in the field and "0.75" (or whatever the Exchange rate is as defined in the Currency record in Settings-->Business Management) in the "base" field. If you leave the currency as USD, both fields will have 1 in them.

The nice thing about this is the historical tracking and reporting. For example, if you buy a widget today for 1 EURO, the system will convert that to your base currency and save it as of that moment, since the exchange rate will probably be different tomorrow, next month, next year, etc. So when you run the report a year from now, you'll know exactly how many sales you made in your base currency, no matter what currency is used on each individual record and no matter how much the exchange rate has fluctuated since then.

Note that the Exchange rate is not dynamically updated for you - you could write a scheduled task or something to pull current exchange rates and update your Currency records in CRM.